# Matching Endpoints of Bipartite Graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to work out this problem:

> Suppose that $G=(V,E)$ is a bipartite graph with bipartition $(V_1, V_2)$ and that $A \subseteq V_1$. Show that the maximum number of vertices of $V_1$ that are the endpoints of a matching of G equals $|V_1| - \text{max}_{A \subseteq V_1} \text{def}(A)$, where $\text{def}(a) = |A| - |N(A)|.$

and I'm really stumped on how to even get started. We were also given the hint:

> Form a larger graph by adding $\text{max}_{A \subseteq V_1} \text{def}(A)$ new vertices to $V_2$ and connect all of them to the vertices of $V_1$.

But I'm not sure how that helps. I think I'm getting stuck because I'm having trouble "seeing" what the question is asking. If anyone has any tips for how to visualize this problem, or how to get started, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It has something to do with Hall's marriage theorem : [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) and look at the graph theory version.

Comment: @AlineParreau I will look into that, thank you.